# If $\mathbb{E}[f(X)]=\mathbb{E}[f(Y)]\,\,\,\forall$ continuous $f$, then $X, Y$ have same distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

> Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space and $X, Y:\Omega \to [0,1]$ be random variables. Prove that if
>
> $$\mathbb{E}[f(X)]=\mathbb{E}[f(Y)] \text{     for all continuous }f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R},$$
>
> then $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution.

My first idea was to prove that $P(X\leq \alpha)=P(Y\leq\alpha)$ for every $\alpha \in [0,1]$, which can be written as $\mathbb{E}[1_{\{X\leq\alpha\}}]=\mathbb{E}[1_{\{Y\leq\alpha\}}]$. Since $1_{\{X\leq\alpha\}}$ and $1_{\{Y\leq\alpha\}}$ may not be continuous, I thought about approximating them by continuous functions, but I'm having trouble to formalize this (not even sure it's possible).

Is there a better way? Thanks!

Comment: Hint: continuous functions are dense in the space of integrable functions.

Answer (score 3):

For any integer $n\ge 1$, consider the function
\begin{align*}
f_n(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1, & x \le \alpha-\frac{1}{n},\\
-n(x-\alpha), & \alpha-\frac{1}{n} < x \le \alpha,\\
0, & x > \alpha.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Then $f_n$ is continuous and $f_n(x) \nearrow 1_{x \le \alpha}$, and
\begin{align*}
E(f_n(X)) \rightarrow P(X \le \alpha).
\end{align*}